# How to apply themes in angular2?

Tags: angular

I need to provide two themes(red, blue) for the web application that I am developing in angular2. When I change the theme, all the components should reflect it?

What are the best practices to apply themes in angular2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DOCUMENT token](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DOCUMENT-let.html) from @angular/platform-browser to gain access to all DOM element and then change the stylesheet source. Below is a simple example.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class SomeComponent {

    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    Light() {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'light.css');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there are two buttons: one for red and other for blue. The theme will change based on button click of user.

Assign button click events as demoed in your HTML:

```
<button (click)="Red()">Red</button>
<button (click)="Blue()">Blue</button>
```

Suppose you want theme change here in div section,

```
<div id="div1">
---
</div>
```

In Angular 2 you have to assign classes dynamically for css.

```
Red(){
document.getElementById('div1').className= 'redClass'; //notice id of div is div1
}

Blue(){
document.getElementById('div1').className='blueClass';
}
```

Now finally, In css change styling according to class:

```
div.redClass {
  background-color :red;
}
div.blueClass {
  background-color :blue;
}
```